# CDL drivers license photo copy

Tags: united-states, driving

Can a person drive a commercial vehicle with a photo copy of their CDL license if they lost or left their CDL license?

Comment: I suspect that it depends on the state.  Certainly, with respect to non-commercial licenses, laws differ on whether you need to carry your license with you when you drive or merely need to *be* licensed.  49 USC 31302 says "No individual shall operate a commercial motor vehicle without a valid commercial driver’s license issued in accordance with section 31308" but there's no indication whether "without" implies a requirement that the license document be carried while driving.

Answer (score 1):

No. No states allow it because it would be too easy to make fake IDs. The police rely on certain security features on your license to authenticate it.